# Grouping data into different categories

Tags: android, sqlite, grouping

I followed this tutorial (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview)
for an expandable list view, in which I enter different shop names, categorized by the part of town they are located:
[image: screenshot]

But there is obviously no need to have the same group several times (which is the case for Neukölln for example).

Here is what I tried to do:

```java
SparseArray<Groups> groups = new SparseArray<Groups>();
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this) ;
List<Shop> shops = db.getAllShops();

    Groups group = null ;
    String str = "null" ;

    int i = 0 ;
    for (Shop shop : shops){
        // if current shop's district differs from district of the shop of the last iteration
        if ( shop.getDistrict() != str ) {
            // making sure that empty group is not appended into groups in the first iteration
            if (group != null) {
                groups.append(i, group);
                i++;
            }
            // saving the district of the current shop
            str = shop.getDistrict();
            // creating a new group named after the current district
            group = new Groups(str);
        }
        // adding shop name to the current district
        group.subitems.add(shop.getName()) ;
    }
    // after last iteration the last group needs to be appended to the groups
    groups.append(i, group);
```

I hope you can understand the basic idea of my code. I sure it has to work out, because I went through it on paper and in theory it works.
My first idea was that those if-statements are responsible, but I have no clue how to repair this.

Comment: I basically used this tutorial on androidhive: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/
In this tutorial the method is called getAllContacts()
I just changed it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `shop.getDistrict() != str` statement will always return true, use `String.equals` instead.
[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Ok, that sounds promising, I will try that out later. Thanks a lot in advance :)